# Get file version from Windows command line for use in a variable?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

How do grab the file version/product version from a file on the Windows 7 command line, to be used in a variable in a `.bat` file?

Comment: Are you referring to actual DOS, or the Windows command line? In any case, please state the OS version you're working with.

Comment: Windows command line

Comment: What kind of file?  How is the version information stored or accessed?

Comment: What version of Windows? There have been some changes between '95 and 7.

Comment: its a .NET app that has its version set from into the Assembly.cs file.. and its Windows 7

Comment: Found this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding you need filever.exe to do this. As pointed out in the comments. Also, I ripped the below word for word from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349588/getting-product-version-from-file-via-cmd-bat)

[How to use the Filever.exe tool to obtain specific information about a file in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913111/en-us)

From what I gather about `filever`'s output it's always in columns and you want the fifth column (version). So a simple `for` should suffice:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%v in ('filever myFile.dll /b') do echo %%v
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I used a vbscript to get the file version, but led me in right direction

Comment: That second link no longer works, just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

You can check using [`sigcheck.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) which is part of [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx), e.g.

```
$ sigcheck.exe -q -n app.exe
5.0.0.1241
```

By specifying `-q` (quiet, no banner) and `-n` will show you only the file version number, so you can assign it into the variable.

---

If you're using Sigcheck64, the 64bit version provided for *Nano Server*, which doesn't support 32bit programs, the `-q` parameter has been replaced by `-nobanner`. E.g.

```
$ sigcheck.exe -nobanner -n app.exe
    5.0.0.1241
```

Source: [What is the difference between Sigcheck and Sigcheck64?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eebc55de-5978-45f1-9930-002ae8e731a7/sigcheck-questions) and [SigCheck manual page](https://ss64.com/nt/sigcheck.html).